# reading data from nested JSON Object using java

Tags: java, json

i am struggling with reading some values from JSON object which i get it when i hit REST API..

**MY GOAL: i need to iterate over each set of data inside data object array check the value of TRAN_ID and take action accordingly.**

below is the format of data

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "CUST_ID": "CUST7",
         "EXPRY_DATE": null,
         "PARAMS": "[{TRAN_IND:savings},{TRAN_TYP:Debit},{country:US}]"
      },
      {
         "CUST_ID": "CUST8",
         "EXPRY_DATE": null,
         "PARAMS": "[{TRAN_IND:current},{TRAN_TYP:Debit},{country:US}]"
      }
   ]
}
```

it looks easy and i have tried multiple solutions out there on internet but i dont know it doesnt work for me and i get below error  while reading "PARAMS" and converting it to JSONArray for further processing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

What i have tried:

```
private static void jsonParser(String jsonStr) throws ParseException {
  JSONObject data= (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(jsonStr );
  JSONArray jsonObj = (JSONArray)data.get("data");
  JSONObject JsonRow = (JSONObject)jsonObj.get(0);
  JSONArray servParam= (JSONArray) JsonRow.get("PARAMS");
  String tran_ind=(String) servParam.get(0);
  System.out.println( tran_ind);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is what you what?

```
     try{
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sample);
            JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");

            for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject detail = data.getJSONObject(i);
                detail.getString("CUST_ID"); //here is the customer id
                detail.getString("EXPRY_DATE"); //here is the exp date
                JSONArray params = detail.getJSONArray("PARAMS");
                for(int j=0; j<params.length(); j++){
//                {TRAN_IND:current},{TRAN_TYP:Debit},{country:US}
                    JSONObject res = params.getJSONObject(j);
                    String tran_ind = res.toString();
                    String tran_type = res.toString();
                    String country = res.toString();

                    out.println(tran_ind + " " +tran_type + " " + country);
                }
            }
        }catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: JSONArray params = detail.getJSONArray("PARAMS"); this return type cast exception... that is a string and i am trying a way to parse it :( thanks you got what i wanted.. :)

Comment: Sorry I did not run that before posting it, but glad you got what you want already.

Comment: hi W.seun... now i want facing issue with the sequence of data in the string... it gets shuffled once after parsing. i want the sequence of data should be in sync with String being passed

Comment: @user1708054 I don't get your question, mind explaining better?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I am converting a string into JSONArrray but the sequence after inserting to JSON it gets changed. I need to maintain sequence of data as what is present in string which is passed for parsing to JSONArray.. but I face issue with ordering in JSONArray.

Comment: @user1708054 that should only happen if the String are not gonna fit in like an array, can I see the strings sample you're using?

Comment: W suen. its a transactional data like [{"party_id":123,"bank_id":100,"tran_id":"12-Aug-2018","tran_amount":250}]..... but when i have gone through the nature of storage in JSON, i found it is unordered because of hashmap being used in there... so i dont think it is something ready functionality which can be used...

Comment: @user1708054 check this out  String sampleData = "[{\"party_id\":123,\"bank_id\":100,\"tran_id\":\"12-Aug-2018\",\"tran_amount\":250}]";
        try {
            JSONArray arrayData = new JSONArray(sampleData);
            JSONObject objs = arrayData.getJSONObject(0);

            System.out.println(objs.getInt("tran_amount"));
            System.out.println(objs.getInt("bank_id"));
            System.out.println(objs.getInt("party_id"));
            System.out.println(objs.getString("tran_id"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: @user1708054 copy and run that code, it's working fine, if you don't mind sharing what you really want to achieve with this? we will solve it faster together.

Answer (score 1):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

=> Because you are trying to parse `String` value `"[{TRAN_IND:savings},{TRAN_TYP:Debit},{country:US}]"` into the JsonArray by code:

```
JSONArray servParam= (JSONArray) JsonRow.get("PARAMS");
```

Comment: exactly!! but how should i proceed ... i tried other ways but nothing seems working for me.. how should i proceed with checking the values inside that.

Comment: String servParam= (String) JsonRow.get("SERV_PARAM"); i have also tried this ... but what after getting into string?? how should i proceed with validating the data inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Params seems to be a String, actually.

Don't write your own parser. If you only need to read that string in each element of the array, I would simply cast the whole JSON to a Map with Jackson:

```
HashMap<String,Object> parsed =
    new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

and then iterate over the "data" element (which would be a list of maps).

```
List<Map> data = (List) parsed.get("data");
```

Comment: i need to check for a value in the JSON object and if that value exist i need to push that record in JSON format to third party.. thats why i need to parse json and do accordingly.. plz help

Comment: Again, you can use Jackson to parse that String

List<String> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_ARRAY_IN_STRING_FORMAT, List.class);

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that those are not nested JSON strings. That would be

```
"PARAMS": "[{\"TRAN_IND\":\"current\"},{\"TRAN_TYP\":\"Debit\"},{\"country\":\"US\"}]"
```

so "text" parts are surrounded by `"`-s inside (which have to be escaped as `\"`-s).
In that case you could write

```
String json=
       "{\n"+
       "  \"data\": [\n"+
       "    {\n"+
       "      \"CUST_ID\": \"CUST7\",\n"+
       "      \"EXPRY_DATE\": null,\n"+
       "      \"PARAMS\": \"[{\\\"TRAN_IND\\\":\\\"savings\\\"},{\\\"TRAN_TYP\\\":\\\"Debit\\\"},{\\\"country\\\":\\\"US\\\"}]\"\n"+
       "    },\n"+
       "    {\n"+
       "      \"CUST_ID\": \"CUST8\",\n"+
       "      \"EXPRY_DATE\": null,\n"+
       "      \"PARAMS\": \"[{\\\"TRAN_IND\\\":\\\"current\\\"},{\\\"TRAN_TYP\\\":\\\"Debit\\\"},{\\\"country\\\":\\\"US\\\"}]\"\n"+
       "    }\n"+
       "  ]\n"+
       "}";
// Print input for clarity:
System.out.println(json);

JSONObject data= (JSONObject)JSONValue.parse(json);
JSONArray jsonObj = (JSONArray)data.get("data");
JSONObject JsonRow = (JSONObject)jsonObj.get(0);

// parse nested JSON
JSONArray servParam= (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse((String)JsonRow.get("PARAMS"));
// array element is an object ({"TRAN_IND":"savings"}), so toString has to be used:
String tran_ind=servParam.get(0).toString();
System.out.println(tran_ind);
```

(The backslash-heaps are there because double-quotes had to be escaped in source code, and also the suggested escaped double quotes. So they would not appear in a JSON file. Try the code in action, it prints the JSON it works on)
So `(JSONArray)JSONValue.parse((String)JsonRow.get("PARAMS"))` would get and parse the nested JSON.

But now you either have to rework the code what generates your input, or parse the nested non-JSON manually.

Comment: thanks :) as per your suggestion i got my input in json format string and would parse the code... accordingly... just wanted to know can we access the value against "TRAN_IND" from that array as it can come at any place in array ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for parsing.

```
String servParam = (String) JsonRow.get("PARAMS");
String servParamSplitted[] = servParam.substring(1, servParam.length() - 1).split(",");
String traind_id[] = servParamSplitted[0].substring(1, servParamSplitted[0].length() - 1).split(":");
String train_id=traind_id[1];
```

I like to add that your JSON should be like below format.

```
 {
   "data":    [
            {
         "CUST_ID": "CUST7",
         "EXPRY_DATE": null,
         "PARAMS": [{"TRAN_IND":"savings"},{"TRAN_TYP":"Debit"},{"country":"US"}]
      },
                {
         "CUST_ID": "CUST8",
         "EXPRY_DATE": null,
         "PARAMS": [{"TRAN_IND":"current"},{"TRAN_TYP":"Debit"},{"country":"US"}]
      }
     ]
   }
```

So, we can parse it using below code.

```
JSONArray servParam = (JSONArray) JsonRow.get("PARAMS");
JSONObject jsonObjectTrainID = (JSONObject) servParam.get(0);
String TrainIDValue = (String) jsonObjectTrainID.get("TRAN_IND");
```